# Google App Script | Email Send on New Sheet Line

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm trying to create an app script sends an email when a new row is added into my Google sheet.

I have everything working for when I manually add in the data. However, when the data is auto added based on a form fill-- the email doesn't send.

I'm thinking that if I add a script that copies & pastes the email address after the new line is created, it will trigger the script to send an email. As of right now, auto-added rows do not send emails.

Thanks for the help!

[Here's a link to my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QxhW-fs2M-YxcfbdKIMDi9GVBuS88YFbhAGd79XTxXI/edit?usp=sharing).

Here's the App Script I'm using:

```
function sendEmailNotificationAndInsertTimestamp_(e) {
  try {
    if (!e) {
      throw new Error('Please do not run the script in the script editor window but set up a trigger. See the instructions in the script.');
    }
    var range = e.range ? e.range : SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
    if (!range || JSON.stringify(e.range) === '{}') {
      return;
    }
    var sheet = range.getSheet();
    if (range.getA1Notation() === 'A1' && sheet.getName() === SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0].getName()) {
      return;
    }
    var notificationSettings = [
      {
        sheetsToWatch: /^(EmailSender)$/i,
        columnLabelsToWatch: ['Email'],
        columnValuesToWatch: [undefined],
        columnLabelsOfEmailAddresses: ['Send to'],
        columnLabelsOfEmailSubjects: ['Subject'],
        columnLabelsOfEmailContents: ['Body'],
        columnLabelsToTimestamp: ['Completed Timestamp'],
        insertTimestamps: [true],
        overwriteTimestamps: [true],
        eraseTimestamps: [false],
        timestampFormat: 'm/d/yyyy h:mm am/pm',
        columnLabelRow: sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1,
      }
    ];
    var rowStart = range.getRow();
    var columnStart = range.getColumn();
    var settings = getSettings_(sheet, notificationSettings);
    if (!settings || rowStart <= settings.columnLabelRow) {
      return;
    }
    var keysToRead = ['columnLabelsToWatch', 'columnLabelsOfEmailAddresses', 'columnLabelsOfEmailSubjects', 'columnLabelsOfEmailContents', 'columnLabelsToTimestamp'];
    var columnLabelArrayLengths = ['columnValuesToWatch'].concat(keysToRead).map(getArrayLengths_(settings));
    if (!isStrictlyEqual_.apply(null, columnLabelArrayLengths)) {
      throw new Error('Mismatch between number of items in ' + keysToRead.join(', ') + '.');
    }
    var keysToWrite = ['columnsToWatch', 'columnsOfEmailAddresses', 'columnsOfEmailSubjects', 'columnsOfEmailContents', 'columnsToTimestamp'];
    if (keysToRead.length !== keysToWrite.length) {
      throw new Error('The number of items in keysToRead differs from the number of items in keysToWrite.');
    }
    var columnNumbers = getColumnNumbers_(sheet, settings, keysToRead, keysToWrite);
    if (!columnNumbers) {
      return;
    }
    var columnNumberArrayLengths = keysToWrite.map(getArrayLengths_(columnNumbers));
    if (!isStrictlyEqual_.apply(null, columnNumberArrayLengths)) {
      throw new Error('Could not find all the columns in ' + keysToRead.join(', ') + '.');
    }
    // iterate modified values
    var now = new Date();
    var emailAddressCheck = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    var values = range.getDisplayValues();
    var emailRecipients = [];
    for (var column = 0, numColumns = values[0].length; column < numColumns; column++) {
      var columnIndex = columnNumbers.columnsToWatch.indexOf(columnStart + column);
      if (columnIndex === -1) {
        continue;
      }
      var toWatch = settings.columnValuesToWatch[columnIndex];
      var regex
        = toWatch === undefined
        ? /./i
        : typeof toWatch === 'string'
        ? new RegExp('^' + escapeRegExCharacters_(toWatch) + '$', 'i')
        : toWatch instanceof RegExp
        ? toWatch
        : null;
      if (!regex) {
        throw new Error('All columnValuesToWatch must be regular expressions or text strings, but "' + toWatch + '" is a ' + (typeof toWatch) + '.');
      }
      for (var row = 0, numRows = values.length; row < numRows; row++) {
        var value = values[row][column];
        if (value === '' && settings.columnValuesToWatch[columnIndex] === undefined) {
          continue;
        }
        if (!value.match(regex)) {
          continue;
        }
        var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(rowStart + row, columnNumbers.columnsOfEmailAddresses[columnIndex]).getDisplayValue().trim();
        var emailSubject = sheet.getRange(rowStart + row, columnNumbers.columnsOfEmailSubjects[columnIndex]).getDisplayValue().trim();
        var emailContents = sheet.getRange(rowStart + row, columnNumbers.columnsOfEmailContents[columnIndex]).getDisplayValue().trim();
        if (emailAddress.split(',').some(address => !address.trim().replace(/^(.+<)|(>$)/g, '').match(emailAddressCheck))
          || [emailAddress, emailSubject, emailContents].some(string => string === '')) {
          throw new Error('Cannot send email with these parameters: To: "' + emailAddress + '", Subject: "' + emailSubject + '", Content: "' + emailContents + '"');
        }
        // send email
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, emailSubject, emailContents);
        emailRecipients.push(emailAddress);
        // insert timestamp
        if (settings.insertTimestamps[columnIndex]) {
          var timestampCell = sheet.getRange(rowStart + row, columnNumbers.columnsToTimestamp[columnIndex]);
          var timestamp
          = value.length
          ? now
          : settings.eraseTimestamps[columnIndex]
          ? null
          : now;
          if (timestamp && !settings.overwriteTimestamps[columnIndex] && timestampCell.getValue()) {
            continue;
          }
          timestampCell.setValue(timestamp).setNumberFormat(settings.timestampFormat);
        }
      } // row
    } // column
    if (emailRecipients.length) {
      showMessage_('Sent email of the status change to ' + emailRecipients.filter(filterUniques_).join(', ') + '.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    showAndThrow_(error);
  }
}    

function getSettings_(sheet, settingsArray) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 26 February 2020
  //  - initial version
  var settings = null;
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  for (var s = 0, numSettings = settingsArray.length; s < numSettings; s++) {
    if (settingsArray[s].sheetsToWatch.test(sheetName)) {
      settings = settingsArray[s];
      break;
    }
  }
  return settings;
}

function getColumnNumbers_(sheet, settings, keysToRead, keysToWrite) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 26 February 2020
  //  - initial version
  var columnLabelRowValues = sheet.getRange(settings.columnLabelRow, /*column*/ 1, /*numRows*/ 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var columnLabels = columnLabelRowValues.map(function stringTrim(value) {
    return String(value).trim();
  });
  var arrays = {};
  for (var k = 0, numKeys = keysToRead.length; k < numKeys; k++) {
    var keyToRead = keysToRead[k];
    var keyToWrite = keysToWrite[k];
    arrays[keyToWrite] = [];
    for (var i = 0, col, numColumns = settings[keyToRead].length; i < numColumns; i++) {
      if ((col = columnLabels.indexOf(settings[keyToRead][i])) !== -1) {
        arrays[keyToWrite].push(col + 1);
      }
    }
  }
  return arrays[keysToWrite[0]].length ? arrays : null;
}

function getArrayLengths_(obj) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde 28 February 2020
  //  - initial version
  var closure = function(key) {
    return obj[key].length;
  };
  return closure;
}

function isStrictlyEqual_(value1, value2) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde 28 February 2020
  //  - initial version
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var numArgs = args.length;
  if (!numArgs) {
    return null;
  }
  var checkAgainst = args[0];
  for (var a = (1); a < numArgs; a++) {
    if (args[a] !== checkAgainst) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function filterUniques_(element, index, array) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 30 May 2019
  //  - initial version
  return array.indexOf(element) === index;
}

function escapeRegExCharacters_(string) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 9 November 2018
  //  - use String
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 30 November 2018
  //  - initial version
  //  - adapted from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions
  return String(string).replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}

function showAndThrow_(error) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 16 April 2020
  //  - initial version
  var stackCodeLines = String(error.stack).match(/\d+:/);
  if (stackCodeLines) {
    var codeLine = stackCodeLines.join(', ').slice(0, -1);
  } else {
    codeLine = error.stack;
  }
  showMessage_(error.message + ' Code line: ' + codeLine, 30);
  throw error;
}

function showMessage_(message, timeoutSeconds) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 16 April 2020
  //  - initial version
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(message, 'Send email notification script', timeoutSeconds || 5);
}

function installOnEditTrigger() {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 9 January 2020
  //  - initial version
  deleteTriggers_(ScriptApp.EventType.ON_EDIT);
  deleteTriggers_(ScriptApp.EventType.ON_CHANGE);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmailNotificationAndInsertTimestamp_')
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
  .onEdit()
  .create();  
}

function installOnFormSubmitTrigger() {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 16 April 2020
  //  - initial version
  deleteTriggers_(ScriptApp.EventType.ON_FORM_SUBMIT);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmailNotificationAndInsertTimestamp_')
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
}

function installOnChangeTrigger() {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 7 May 2020
  //  - initial version
  deleteTriggers_(ScriptApp.EventType.ON_EDIT);
  deleteTriggers_(ScriptApp.EventType.ON_CHANGE);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmailNotificationAndInsertTimestamp_')
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
  .onChange()
  .create();
}

function deleteTriggers_(triggerType) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 7 May 2020
  //  - initial version
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0, numTriggers = triggers.length; i < numTriggers; i++) {
    if (triggers[i].getEventType() === triggerType) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: onChange trigger does not fire when other scripts make the change.  It must be a user change.

Comment: Have you tried on form submit?

Comment: that is a limitation. try other triggers such as on form submit